# Error in javascript array when i pass a if

Tags: javascript

I have to create an array and check if is even his numbers, so far so good. I ran the code and it appears when I print the second array:

```
[ 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 7, 6 ]

[ 0, 0, <1 empty item>, 2, <3 empty items>, 0, <1 empty item>, 6 ]
```

Why do I get `<n empty item>` entries in my array?

```
var numb = [];
for (let x=0; x<10; x++) {
    numb.push(Math.round(Math.random() * x))    
} console.log(numb)

var numbpar = [];

for (let x=0; x<10; x++) {
    if (numb[x] % 2 === 0) {
        numbpar[x] = numb[x];        
    }    
}
console.log(numbpar)
```

Comment: What the expected value to be added to numbpar when numb[x] is not even?

Comment: Can you include all your code? `numb` is undefined in the provided

Comment: `numbpar.push(numb[x])`

Comment: You say to put a else after the if?

Comment: Well push resolve my problem thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you say

```
for(let x=0; x<10; x++){
    if (numb[x] % 2 === 0) {
        numbpar[x] = numb[x]

    }

}
```

this code means
if numb[x] is even Xth of numbpar Member is equal numb[x] other mean's is if not even this member is empty 
you must change to this

```
for(let x=0; x<10; x++){
    if (numb[x] % 2 === 0) {
        numbpar.push(numb[x])

    }

}
```

in this code add to array only when numb[x] is even